# Always allow Local Pickup in WooCommerce on Postcode restrictions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Allowing shipping based on postcodes in a zone disables all shipping methods in that zone for example if I have a **Local zone** which contains, *Local Pickup and Flat Rate* and they are restricted to only certain specified postcodes then neither is available. (Of course that's the design of WooCommerce).

However I'd like to allow local pickup for all postcodes and not just the restricted ones inside the same zone?

I can create a new zone and put local delivery inside that so if they're not in the area then the other zone will be active however it feels like it's counter productive to do the same thing with two different zones.

Comment: I think that you don't have another choice that having multiple repetitive Zones for that…

Comment: Loic I was waiting to see what you say! You're the woo expert! I guess I'll take that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your shipping method (Local pickup) to the zone: **Locations not covered by your other zones**

This zone covers all the cases not covered in your created zones.

Edit: And yes, you will need to repeat local pickup method, in your zone and the default zone, it's not counter productive, it's the way WooCommerce works :)

Comment: Accepted although I already knew that and stated in my question however so your effort isn't wasted!